# How to alter a value before storing it to the database in Keystone JS

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs

Keystone and mongo are both new to me, so I'm unsure how to manipulate data.

I have a Keystone list which has a model (`/models/Game.js`) that looks like:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Game = new keystone.List('Game');

Game.add({
    odds: { type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true},
});

Game.track = true;
Game.defaultSort = '-createdAt';
Game.defaultColumns = 'odds';
Game.register();
```

The odds field is a string, e.g. `3/1`, and I want to run this through a function that splits it and returns a decimal version, for example:

```
function decimalOdds(fraction) {
    const splitFields = fraction.split('/');
    return ((splitFields[0] / splitFields[1]) + 1).toFixed(2);
}
```

It's the return value of that function that I want to be stored as the 'odds' in the data base.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pre save hook:

```
Game.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isModified('odds')) {
    this.odds = decimalOdds(this.odds)
  }
  next()
})
```

You can read more in the **schema plugins** section of the docs:
http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-plugins

You can also find more information on Mongoose schema hooks here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Thank you!  Having read the Keystone schema docs and tested a couple things I notice that it makes no difference if I use `Post.schema.methods.decimalOdds = function(fraction) { ... }` combined with `this.decimalOdds(this.odds)` or if I just define a normal function like `function decimalOdds(fraction) { ... }` and call it just by `decimalOdds(this.odds)`.  Is there a difference between the two approaches?

Comment: No problem. Creating a Mongoose instance method will allow you to use that method wherever you have an instance of the model so this might be useful if you were to use your model elsewhere in your application and needed that functionality.

Comment: Awesome.  Sorry one last thing (accidentally extending my question a tiny bit).  If you have multiple `pre` hooks, can they all be inside the same `Game.schema.pre` or does each one have this entire block?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple ***pre save*** blocks and each one will fire when the preceding one finishes (when ***next()*** is called). They should fire in the order that they are defined. There's also no reason why you can't put additional functionality inside the one block if you want.