# Adding a new property to mongo after 'save' in Keystone

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs

I recently found out how to change the value of an existing property and saving it to the mongo database when using Keystone JS ([How to alter a value before storing it to the database in Keystone JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667631/how-to-alter-a-value-before-storing-it-to-the-database-in-keystone-js)).

Now I need to add a new property and save it to the database during the same `pre('save')` phase.

The aims is to say, if the result (existing property) of a game is 'Won', then add a new property 'won' which is a boolean (true).  If it matters, the reason I want this is because in a handlebars template I want to say `{{#if won}}class="success"{{/if}}`

```
Game.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.isModified('result')) {
        if (this.result === 'Won') {
            this.won = true;
        }
    }
    next()
});
```

But nothing happens.  I read that you can't add properties unless they've been set in the schema.  So I tried adding `Game.schema.set('won', false);` above that, but still nothing.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at Mongoose **virtuals** which are properties that you can get and set but that do not get persisted to the database:

```
Game.schema.virtual('won').get(function() {
  return this.result === 'Won'
})
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

If you just want to use it in your template then you could also set a specific property on **locals** in your view.

Perhaps something like this:

```
...

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

  var view = new keystone.View(req, res)

  var locals = res.locals

  locals.games = []

  view.on('init', function(next) {

    var query = {} // Add query here

    Game.model.find(query).exec(function(err, games) {

      // Handle error

      games.forEach(function(game) {
        game.won = game.result === 'Won'
      })

      locals.games = games

    })

  })

}

...
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting.
The `locals.won` would be set on the results as a whole, rather than per result.  Would there be a way to loop through each result and add the property to locals for each one?

Comment: I have edited my answer to find multiple games and add the **won** property to each one. Hope this helps.